# Naming a Drive with a Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a command to rename a few drives that I map every start-up in WinXP. I've got the mapping part down, I'm now interested in naming them programmatically with custom names, so I can keep them straight.

Comment: What did you have in mind as a "custom name"?  That is, how would you use this name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I gave up on DOS and learned PowerShell instead. The end result worked like this:

```
$Net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network  
$Rename = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  

#### # Map the local drives  
Subst Q: 'C:\File Path\Uno'    
Subst U: 'C:\File Path\Dos' 

#### # Map the network drives  
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("X:", '\\Server\File Path\Uno')  
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("Y:", '\\Different Server\File Path\Dos')

#### # Rename everything  
$rename.NameSpace("Q:\").Self.Name = 'Network -> FOO'  
$rename.NameSpace("U:\").Self.Name = 'Network -> BAR'  
$rename.NameSpace("X:\").Self.Name = 'Local -> FOO'  
$rename.NameSpace("Y:\").Self.Name = 'Local -> BAR'
```

Answer (score 4):

From a command prompt, enter:

```
LABEL x: yourlabel
```

Where `x:` is your drive letter, and `yourlabel` the name you'd like it to have.

From `LABEL /?`:

```
Creates, changes, or deletes the volume label of a disk.

LABEL [drive:][label]
LABEL [/MP] [volume] [label]

  drive:          Specifies the drive letter of a drive.
  label           Specifies the label of the volume.
  /MP             Specifies that the volume should be treated as a
                  mount point or volume name.
  volume          Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                  mount point, or volume name.  If volume name is specified,
                  the /MP flag is unnecessary.
```

---

Edit:
As @mark pointed out, this does not work with mapped drives. It seems this is a common problem, and there may be a way to achieve this via the [registry](https://superuser.com/questions/198499/change-network-drive-label-by-command-line), or somewhat easier, by using a small [vbs script](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1105).

Comment: Actually, you can't use label on a mapped drive.  I'm not sure there's a solution to this one.

Comment: You're right. Looks like the registry or something like a vbs needs to fill the gap...

Comment: vbs does the trick:  `mDrive = "q:\" <br>
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") <br>
oShell.NameSpace(mDrive).Self.Name = "AnyName"` (<br> as I can't enter a new line in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
 REM  ad label to any drive
 set SETl=TEMP
 set SETD=B
 echo strComputer = "." > LTEMP.vbs && echo Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ >> LTEMP.vbs && echo     + "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" + strComputer + "\root\cimv2") >> LTEMP.vbs && echo.  >> LTEMP.vbs && echo Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ >> LTEMP.vbs && echo     ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID = '%SETD%:'") >> LTEMP.vbs && echo.  >> LTEMP.vbs && echo For Each objDrive in colDrives >> LTEMP.vbs && echo     objDrive.VolumeName = "%SETl%" >> LTEMP.vbs && echo     objDrive.Put_ >> LTEMP.vbs && echo Next >> LTEMP.vbs && cscript LTEMP.vbs && del LTEMP.vbs
```