# Creating a powershell batch file to create a disk label from existing persistent network shares

Tags: powershell, batch-file, wsh, network-share, subst

I'm  trying to create a batch file using windows powershell that will look for existing persistent network shares and take their path to create a name, much like a custom disk label.

I'm a novice but know the start point can be based on the following, although this needs taking a step further to look for existing shares, to run on stratup, and to be executable each time a new share is added.

Thanks,

```
$Net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network  
$Rename = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  

#### # Map the local drives  
Subst Q: 'C:\File Path\Uno'    
Subst U: 'C:\File Path\Dos' 

#### # Map the network drives  
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("X:", '\\Server\File Path\Uno')  
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("Y:", '\\Different Server\File Path\Dos')

#### # Rename everything  
$rename.NameSpace("Q:\").Self.Name = 'Network -> FOO'  
$rename.NameSpace("U:\").Self.Name = 'Network -> BAR'  
$rename.NameSpace("X:\").Self.Name = 'Local -> FOO'  
$rename.NameSpace("Y:\").Self.Name = 'Local -> BAR'
```

my rational follows similarly on from:
[Naming a Drive with a Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608840/naming-a-drive-with-a-batch-file)

This is my first post here and I'm grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Symbolic Links instead :

```
mklink /d c:\foo \\foo\bar
```

Comment: of no benefit, this does not ctreate a drive letter and path, or am I missing something