# Setting the name of a SUBST drive using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm using SUBST to create a drive letter representing a path on a local drive.

```
subst Q: "C:\Users\Username\My Documents\blah\blah\blah"
```

I want to label the new drive E: with a descriptive name different than the volume name of C: 
This cannot be done through Explorer, or using the LABEL command.

A solution is offered in this [question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608840/naming-a-drive-with-a-batch-file). It includes a snippet of VBS code to set a drive name in the comments. @SeanC implied that it worked properly back then.

The code looks like this when expanded:

```
mDrive = "q:\"
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.NameSpace(mDrive).Self.Name = "AnyName"
```

In 2019, under Windows 10, this code does not work:

```
C:\Label_drive.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'oShell.NameSpace(...)'
```

I'm not at all familiar with VBS - can anyone identify the problem with the script? What has changed that would cause this error now?

Edit: This command is run from an administrator (elevated) command window prompt:

```
cscript Label_drive.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

This powershell script works for me :

```
$a = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$a.NameSpace( "P:\" ).self.name = "Dev"
```

Source : https://superuser.com/questions/198499/change-network-drive-label-by-command-line